# Codeigniter - configure enable_query_strings and form_open

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter

I want to be able to user query strings in this fashion. `Domain.com/controller/function?param=5&otherparam=10`

In my config file I have

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8888/test-sites/domain.com/public_html';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

The problem that I am getting is that `form_open` is automatically adding a question mark (?) to my url.

So if I say:

```
echo form_open('account/login');
```

it spits out: `http://localhost:8888/test-sites/domain.com/public_html/?account/login`

Notice the question mark it added right before "account".

How can I fix this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of your problem is in the Core Config.php file where the CI_Config class resides. The method site_url() is used by the form helper when you are trying to use form_open function.
Solution would be to override this class with your own. If you are using CI < 2.0 then create your extended class in application/libraries/MY_Config.php, otherwise if CI >= 2.0 then your extended class goes to application/core/MY_Config.php.
Then you need to redefine the method site_url().

```
class MY_Config extends CI_Config
{
   function __construct()
   {
      parent::CI_Config();
   }

   public function site_url($uri='')
   {
      //Copy the method from the parent class here:
      if ($uri == '')
      {
         if ($this->item('base_url') == '')
     {
        return $this->item('index_page');
     }
     else
     {
        return $this->slash_item('base_url').$this->item('index_page');
     }
      }

      if ($this->item('enable_query_strings') == FALSE)
      {
         //This is when query strings are disabled
      }
      else
      {
         if (is_array($uri))
     {
        $i = 0;
        $str = '';
        foreach ($uri as $key => $val)
        {
           $prefix = ($i == 0) ? '' : '&';
           $str .= $prefix.$key.'='.$val;
           $i++;
        }
            $uri = $str;
         }
         if ($this->item('base_url') == '')
     {
            //You need to remove the "?" from here if your $config['base_url']==''
        //return $this->item('index_page').'?'.$uri;
            return $this->item('index_page').$uri;
     }
     else
     {
            //Or remove it here if your $config['base_url'] != ''
        //return $this->slash_item('base_url').$this->item('index_page').'?'.$uri;
            return $this->slash_item('base_url').$this->item('index_page).$uri;
     }
      }
   }
}
```

I hope this helps and I think you are using CI 2.0 that wasn't officially released, this was removed in the official CI 2.0 version

Comment: This will remove the question mark from the redirect() function in your url helper too, otherwise it wont work properly.

Comment: Make sure you name the file MY_Config.php and not MY_config.php. Using a lowercase c will work on Windows because Windows is case insensitive but it will not work on unix machines.

Answer (score 2):

Simpler might be to just set follwing in your **config.php**

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

Was the solution in my case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use query string in your url structure, then you should manually type your url structure in the following order:

```
<domain.com>?c={controller}&m={function}&param1={val}&param2={val}
```

in the action of the resepective controller you should get the parameter as `$_GET['param1']`

your code now should look like this

```
form_open(c=account&m=login&param1=val)
```

Please let me know if it doesnt work for you.